# adding more rows to jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

The basic autocomplete is bound to an ajax call and the results get shown fine. When I scroll down, I need to get more data and append that to the already displayed autocomplete list, without closing the existing open dropdown.

1. Tried adding the source option to the new list, but the new entries do not show up.

   `$( "auto" ).autocomplete("option","source",autocompletesource);
   Here autocompletesource contains old results and new results.`
2. Tried the _renderItem. Same problem, they do not show up in the dropdown.

   $.each(results, function (index, item) {
   $("#auto").autocomplete().data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
       return $( "

   " ).data("item.autocomplete", item)
           .append( "" + item.value + "" + item.label )
           .appendTo( ul );
   }; 
   });
3. Appended as below. The results show up in the list, but on selection or even mousing over, get a MenuFocus error for undefined item.value

   $( ".ui-autocomplete" ).append( "
  " ).data("item.autocomplete", item)
              .append( ""+item.label+""); 
          });

I am not sure if option 3 is even the correct way of doing it. Maybe there is already something in the autocomplete component, which I am not using. And if I have to go with option 3, how do I remove the MenuFocus error.

Answer (score 0):

For now, the only way I could manage to get and add more rows on scrolling within autocomplete is as follows:

```
$( ".ui-autocomplete" ).scroll(function() {
var $this = $(this);
var isbottom=isScrollbarBottom($(this));
if(isbottom) {
  //make an ajax call   
  $.ajax({
    //get your incremental data and iterate thru the result and add them
    $.each(results, function (index, item) {
/*   this works for display but no selection ; 
    selection added manually via function select_dynamic_row;
*/

      $( ".ui-autocomplete" ).append( '<li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-'+item.value+' tabindex="-1" onclick=\'select_dynamic_row("'+item.value+'","'+encodeURIComponent(item.label)+'")\'>'+item.label+'</li>' );
      }); 
  }
});

function isScrollbarBottom(container) {
 var height = container.outerHeight();
 var scrollHeight = container[0].scrollHeight;
 var scrollTop = container.scrollTop();
 if (scrollTop >= scrollHeight - height) {
         return true;
  }
  return false;
};

function select_dynamic_row(label,value){
 //do whatever with the selected value
}
```